# IOS how to get the pixel value of the image

Tags: android, ios, swift

I want to get the pixel value from image not color.Android has `int getPixel(x, y)` method,Is there a similar implementation in iOS? Note that I want to get the pixel value, not the color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1262893/467209).  The linked answer returns a UIColor object, but that is created from the RGB data that is read, so it is available.

You can modify that answer to match [Android's documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html):

> The components are stored as follows (alpha << 24) | (red << 16) |
>   (green << 8) | blue

```
red = rawData[byteIndex];
green = rawData[byteIndex + 1];
blue = rawData[byteIndex + 2];
alpha = rawData[byteIndex + 3];

NSInteger pixel = (alpha << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue; // 32 or 64bits depending on device
int32_t androidPixel = (int32_t)pixel; // Guaranteed 32 bits like android/java `int`
```

Note that although android's documentation implies this is an `int`, a color such as opaque black looks like `0xFF000000`, meaning it will appear as a negative number in a 32 bit int.  Using an unsigned integer or 64 bit integer will appear to have a different result although the bits are the same.

Comment: I don't want RGB,I want a pixel value,like Android's `int getPixel(x, y)` method. `get Pixel(x, y)` method return a int value, not RGB.

Comment: @发抖喵小咪 That "int value" is an int encoding 4 byte components (ARGB)

Comment: i got a positive integer through this method,but android's `int getPixel(x, y)` method get a negtive integer. then what can i do?

Comment: all values of android is negtive integer.

Answer (score 0):

Getting pixel size is simple task. There two ways you can get image pixel size. Try one of the following method.

1. Using `cgImage`

   ```
   let image = UIImage(named: "test")
   let width = image?.cgImage.width // Pixel width
   let height = image?.cgImage.height // Pixel height
   let imageSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height) //Image Pixel Size
   print("Image Pixel Size: \(imageSize)")
   ```
2. Using PNG Data

   ```
   let image = UIImage(named: "test")
   let imageData: Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)! // Get PNG Image Data
   let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData)!  // Get image from PNG Data
   let  imageSize = image.size // Finally get size from png Image
   print("Image Pixel Size: \(imageSize)")
   ```

Comment: Your answer is not what I want.